# Missing Covariates in Darts TimeSeries

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, transformer-model

I'm putting together a TFT model in the darts library in python and I keep getting the same error.  Here's roughly what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from darts import TimeSeries, concatenate
from darts.dataprocessing.transformers import Scaler
from darts.models import TFTModel
from darts.metrics import mape
from darts.utils.statistics import check_seasonality, plot_acf
from darts.utils.timeseries_generation import datetime_attribute_timeseries
from darts.utils.likelihood_models import QuantileRegression

f_columns = ['Year', 'Month', 'Week', 'DayOfMonth', 'DayOfWeek', 'WeekOfMonth', 'Season', 'Holidays', 'Weekend']
QUANTILES = [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95, 0.99]
ICL = 60
OCL = 15

time_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(data, time_col='CreateDate', value_cols=f_columns + ['Count'], freq = 'D')
train, test = time_series.split_after(SPLIT)

scaler = Scaler()
train_data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train)
test_data_scaled = scaler.transform(test)

model = TFTModel(
      input_chunk_length=ICL,
      output_chunk_length=OCL,
      hidden_size=16,
      lstm_layers=2,
      num_attention_heads=1,
      dropout=0.1,
      batch_size=16,
      n_epochs=2,
      likelihood = QuantileRegression(quantiles=QUANTILES),
      )

model.fit(series = train_data_scaled['Count'],
      past_covariates = train_data_scaled[f_columns],
      future_covariates = test_data_scaled[f_columns],
      verbose=True
     )

preds = model.predict(test_data_scaled)
preds = scaler.inverse_transform(preds)
```

When I run this I consistently get the error

```
Missing covariates; could not find past covariates in index value range: 2020-08-22 00:00:00 - 2020-10-20 00:00:00
```

However any time I change the input or output chunk lengths these dates change accordingly.  Whenever I look at the data though, there is valid data in whatever time window it claims there are no past covariates.  I'm really unsure what the problem is here.  Let me know how I can amend this issue and get my model working.

This was also a problem someone posted on [Github](https://github.com/unit8co/darts/issues/1086) but they didn't post a definitive answer and the OP's explanation of how they resolved the issue wasn't detailed enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you’re experiencing is because of the way you’re slicing the past and future covariates from the scaled time series. When using the fit method in the TFTModel, you should provide the past_covariates and future_covariates as TimeSeries objects, not DataFrames.

Answer (score 0):

The past covariates have to cover* and extend further into the past than your `series=`. Similarly, the future covariates have to cover* and extend further into the future.

How much further is determined by your `ICL` and `OCL` variables.

By using the same data set for `series` as for `past_covariates`, you aren't extending the past covariates back far enough into the past, hence the error.

By using the test set for the future covariates, you won't have a future covariate for the earlier steps in `series`.

To solve this error, you can start your `series` at least OCL steps past the start of `past_covariates`

*Technically, the past covariates only have to go to the series end - ICL and the future covariates only have to go to the series start + OCL.